# CloudWatch Alarm for Status Check Failed isn't being created

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

This code sample is similar to what I am using to create CPU, Disk, and Memory alarms in CloudWatch. I am wanting to create alarms for all instances for CloudWatch StatusCheckFailed. Would someone tell me why the StatusCheckFailed alarm isn't getting created?

```
import boto3, sys

# Create EC2 resourcestr(sys.argv)
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

# Getting all running instances
#instances = ec2.instances.all()

# Create CloudWatch client
cw = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# Initialize i_name and i_div variables with instance Name and Costcenter tags
for i in instances:
    i_name = "unnamed"
    for tag in i.tags:
        if tag['Key'] == "Name":
            i_name = tag['Value']
        if tag["Key"] == 'Costcenter':
            i_div = tag['Value']

# List all metrics with namespace as CWAgent, metric-name as Memory % Committed Bytes In Use and partial dimension as instanceid
    listOfMetrics = cw.list_metrics(
        Namespace = '"AWS/EC2"',
        MetricName = 'StatusCheckFailed',
        Dimensions = [
            {
                'Name': 'InstanceId',
                'Value': i.id
            }
        ]
    )

# Check if StatusCheckFailed metrics exists
    if listOfMetrics['Metrics'] != []:
        # Check the state of the instance to see if it is running
        if i.state["Name"] == "running" :
            # Create the alarm
            for metric in listOfMetrics['Metrics']:
                putAlarm = cw.put_metric_alarm (
                    AlarmName = i_div + "-" + i_name + "-(" + i.id + ")-" + "StatusCheckFailed",
                    AlarmDescription = 'Status check for %s %s' % (i.id, i_name),
                    ComparisonOperator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
                    ActionsEnabled = True,
                    AlarmActions = [alarm],
                    Statistic = "Maximum",
                    EvaluationPeriods = 2,
                    Threshold = 1.0,
                    Period = 60,
                    Dimensions = [{
                        'Name': 'InstanceId', 
                        'Value': i.id
                        }
                    ]
                )
```

Comment: What is `alarm` in `AlarmActions = [alarm]`? Its not defined anywhere?

Comment: The 'alarm' variable represents an SNS Topic ARN. I removed that block of code because of the ARNs that were embedded in an if, elsif, elsif statement.

Comment: I have an if elif statement that assigns an SNS topic to the alarm variable based on the Costcenter tag or i_div variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Namespace = 'AWS/EC2' had double quotes in it as well Namespace = '"AWS/EC2"'   In making the code uniform I was setting all the strings in single quotes, replacing double quotes. For the Namespace string I overlooked removing the double quotes. This script is running as expected now.